# How to assign the user login block to header region

Tags: users

I created a user and I logged in as the user by visiting xxx.com/user. I just visited xxx.com/user. I see the user name but I do not see any log out button. I am not sure how I logout.

Thanks.

D

Answer (score 0):

The Drupal core *User login* block doesn't display a login/logout link; it only displays a form for logging in an anonymous user. If you want a block to display logout, the *User Menu* block displays user-specific menu links that also includes a logout link when a user is logged in.

Answer (score 0):

As Shawn says. Or, create your own logout link in whatever menu you are using (if you are). As an example, using the 'main menu' in Drupal 7:
yoursite/admin/structure/menu/manage/main-menu/add
Menu link title: Logout
Path: user/logout